# How to echo data from id

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I assume this must be simple, but I'm just stuck on a solution here. How would I echo data from the id in the database? I cannot edit the css div where I display this data so need to find out a way to cut down the PHP, for example:

```
<?  $query = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id='1'";

        $result_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id=1");
        $result_2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id=2");
        $result_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id=3");



        while($row_1 = mysql_fetch_array($result_1))
        while($row_2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_2))
        while($row_3 = mysql_fetch_array($result_3))


          { ?>
```

From here I echo the data in a div:

```
<? echo $row_1['name'] ?>
```

What I am trying to do is something like this: echo $row_1['name']['1']. I want to somewhat use the WHERE id=1 inside my echo. Sorry if this is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to get [told off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I cannot edit the css div where I display this data???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo ($row['id'] == 1) ? $row['id'] : ''; // print id only when id == 1
}
```

**Notice:** This extension (*mysql_**) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `example`"); // Select all columns and rows from the example table

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // For each row returned
    print($row['id'] . " - " . $row['name'] . "<br />\n"); // Print the row's ID and name
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do an if() just before the echo, like below:

```
<? if($row_1['id'] == 1) echo $row_1['name']; ?>
```

Or from what we know, your results in $row_1 will always have id == 1, since you specified it in the query.

Hope this helps, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo ($row['id'] == 1) ? $row['id'] : ''; // print id only when id == 1
}
```